# How to change seedbox/torrent ip show as domain name?

Tags: bittorrent

how to change my seedbox ip address showing as domain name. Ex: this.is.feralhosting.com (i saw in the peers list).

any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know in qbittorrent at least  its in the advanced settings:

'IP to declare to tracker'    use the  IP from your nslockup or whois